# node-proxy works with host:port but doesn't take a unix socket-path

Tags: sockets, node.js, ubuntu, vhosts

I want to do some vhost-jiggery-pokery with [`node-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). Consider that I have a slave script up and running, which listens on a unix-socket: `/tmp/node-http/cubixcraft.de`
When I want to load it into my node-proxy with the following script it simply doesn't work. The webpage doesn't respond.

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    httpProxy = require("http-proxy");

var options = {
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        "cubixcraft.de": "/tmp/node-http/cubixcraft.de"
    }
};

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);
```

When I use normal ports instead of socket-paths everything works just fine. I even fired a get request on the socket-path that successfully finished. The path really works. There seems to be something wrong with the node-proxy.

Is anybody experiencing the same problems?

Comment: I wanted to do something similar recently, but according to the open github issue here https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/104 it is not possible yet.

Comment: Seems like they broke it, while fixing it... Genius. Do you wanna post an answer so I have something to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to do something similar recently, but according to the open github issue here http://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/104 it is not possible yet.

Comment: I fixed it myself. If you still want to use sockets, [you now can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10800727/420747).

Answer (score 0):

As [zi42 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792391/node-proxy-works-with-hostport-but-doesnt-take-a-unix-socket-path/10792487#10792487) this behaviour is a bug. I digged into the code and found out, that they don't care about sockets. There is not a single line that deals with `socketsPath`s.

Since nobody has respond to the [issue](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/104) in a long time [I fixed it myself](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/104#issuecomment-5983929). You can find the result [here](https://gist.github.com/2828473). This is a wrapper-module that includes `socketPath`'s. I will make a [pull request](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/pull/254), so that `socketPath`s will work by default soon.

The following example shows how to use it. I assume, that you have a HTTP-server listening on the socket "/tmp/node-http/myserver.com".

```
var httpProxy = require("./fixed-http-proxy.js"); // This assumes that you have my .js in your cwd and http-proxy installed as a module (npm install http-proxy)

console.log(httpProxy);
var options = {
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        "myserver.com": "/tmp/node-http/myserver.com" // Sockets are determined by a leading slash
    }
};

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80); // myserver.com:80 now internally proxies to /tmp/node-http/myserver.com
```